# CSS opacity transition on page open

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want my CSS div to be completely invisible when page opens but after 2s appear on screen.
I tried setting opacity: 0; and then transition: opacity 100 2s; but it didn't work. I don't want CTA for example for it to happen after they hover or something but instead I want it to happen even if the user doesn't move the mouse. Please help!

Comment: please use a code snippet (ctrl + m) to show your coding attempt.

Comment: opacity should be between 0-1. opacity :0 => 0%,  opacity : 1 => 100%

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS animation to make it. Like this-
HTML-

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

And CSS-

```
<style>
.div{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    animation-name:opacity;
    animation-duration:4s;
}
    @keyframes opacity{
    0%{opacity:0;}
    100%{opacity:1;}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

U can simply use CSS animations instead of transition.
consider HTML code having single div element

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

now to apply CSS animation we do something like this,

```
#main{
   ...add your desired code for styling the div...
   animation-name:onload;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-delay: 2s;  //this is the key line, what this means is the animation would start after 2s of delay.
```

}

// Now creating animation

```
@keyframes onload{
    0%{
       opacity:0;
    }
    100%{
       opacity: 1;
    }
}
```